# ActionBase is not showing in Adaptive Card

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

my nuget packages and its version for adaptive card.

**Package Name**: Microsoft.AdaptiveCards
**Version**=0.5.1.0

When i installed this package, I can see *`List<ActionBase>`*  to add all adaptive card actions .

Code Sample for **Version**=0.5.1.0:

```
                    List<ActionBase> actionList = new List<ActionBase>();
                    ShowCardAction action1 = new ShowCardAction();
                    action1.Title = "View Comment";
                    actionList.Add(action1);
                    ShowCardAction action2 = new ShowCardAction();
                    action2.Title = "Post Comment";
                    actionList.Add(action2);
                    OpenUrlAction action3 = new OpenUrlAction();
                    action3.Title = "View  Ticket";
                    action3.Url = "<URL>;
                    actionList.Add(action3);
```

**Package Name**: AdaptiveCards
**Version**=1.0.0

When i installed this package, I cannt see *`List<ActionBase>`* due to latest version. **How can i add multiple card actions?**

Answer (score 1):

In AdaptiveCards Version=1.0.0, ActionBase has been changed to AdaptiveAction.

This should work:

```
List<AdaptiveAction> actionList = new List<AdaptiveAction>();
AdaptiveShowCardAction action1 = new AdaptiveShowCardAction();
action1.Title = "View Comment";
actionList.Add(action1);
AdaptiveShowCardAction action2 = new AdaptiveShowCardAction();
action2.Title = "Post Comment";
actionList.Add(action2);
AdaptiveOpenUrlAction action3 = new AdaptiveOpenUrlAction();
action3.Title = "View  Ticket";
action3.Url = new Uri("<URL>");
actionList.Add(action3);
```